# Sonar runner execution with Jenkins failed cause of unexpected end of stream

Tags: jenkins, sonarqube, sonar-runner

Sonar runner execution with Jenkins failed cause of unexpected end of stream and \n not found exception. I am executing big project( 10K php files) job via jenkins sonar runner and continually getting following errors. Please help me to fix it.

```
INFO: ------------------------------------------------------------------------
ERROR: Error during SonarQube Scanner execution
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Fail to request http://sonar.entrata.lcl:9000/api/ce/submit?projectKey=Optimization&projectName=Optimization
    at org.sonarqube.ws.client.HttpConnector.doCall(HttpConnector.java:204)
    at org.sonarqube.ws.client.HttpConnector.post(HttpConnector.java:167)
    at org.sonarqube.ws.client.HttpConnector.call(HttpConnector.java:137)
    at org.sonar.scanner.bootstrap.BatchWsClient.call(BatchWsClient.java:69)
    at org.sonar.scanner.report.ReportPublisher.upload(ReportPublisher.java:173)
    at org.sonar.scanner.report.ReportPublisher.execute(ReportPublisher.java:128)
    at org.sonar.scanner.phases.PublishPhaseExecutor.publishReportJob(PublishPhaseExecutor.java:64)
    at org.sonar.scanner.phases.PublishPhaseExecutor.executeOnRoot(PublishPhaseExecutor.java:51)
    at org.sonar.scanner.phases.AbstractPhaseExecutor.execute(AbstractPhaseExecutor.java:81)
    at org.sonar.scanner.scan.ModuleScanContainer.doAfterStart(ModuleScanContainer.java:184)
    at org.sonar.core.platform.ComponentContainer.startComponents(ComponentContainer.java:142)
    at org.sonar.core.platform.ComponentContainer.execute(ComponentContainer.java:127)
    at org.sonar.scanner.scan.ProjectScanContainer.scan(ProjectScanContainer.java:241)
    at org.sonar.scanner.scan.ProjectScanContainer.scanRecursively(ProjectScanContainer.java:236)
    at org.sonar.scanner.scan.ProjectScanContainer.doAfterStart(ProjectScanContainer.java:226)
    at org.sonar.core.platform.ComponentContainer.startComponents(ComponentContainer.java:142)
    at org.sonar.core.platform.ComponentContainer.execute(ComponentContainer.java:127)
    at org.sonar.scanner.task.ScanTask.execute(ScanTask.java:47)
    at org.sonar.scanner.task.TaskContainer.doAfterStart(TaskContainer.java:86)
    at org.sonar.core.platform.ComponentContainer.startComponents(ComponentContainer.java:142)
    at org.sonar.core.platform.ComponentContainer.execute(ComponentContainer.java:127)
    at org.sonar.scanner.bootstrap.GlobalContainer.executeTask(GlobalContainer.java:115)
    at org.sonar.batch.bootstrapper.Batch.executeTask(Batch.java:118)
    at org.sonarsource.scanner.api.internal.batch.BatchIsolatedLauncher.execute(BatchIsolatedLauncher.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.sonarsource.scanner.api.internal.IsolatedLauncherProxy.invoke(IsolatedLauncherProxy.java:60)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy0.execute(Unknown Source)
    at org.sonarsource.scanner.api.EmbeddedScanner.doExecute(EmbeddedScanner.java:240)
    at org.sonarsource.scanner.api.EmbeddedScanner.runAnalysis(EmbeddedScanner.java:151)
    at org.sonarsource.scanner.cli.Main.runAnalysis(Main.java:110)
    at org.sonarsource.scanner.cli.Main.execute(Main.java:72)
    at org.sonarsource.scanner.cli.Main.main(Main.java:60)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: unexpected end of stream on okhttp3.Address@e2108c1d
    at okhttp3.internal.http.Http1xStream.readResponse(Http1xStream.java:199)
    at okhttp3.internal.http.Http1xStream.readResponseHeaders(Http1xStream.java:125)
    at okhttp3.internal.http.HttpEngine.readNetworkResponse(HttpEngine.java:775)
    at okhttp3.internal.http.HttpEngine.access$200(HttpEngine.java:86)
    at okhttp3.internal.http.HttpEngine$NetworkInterceptorChain.proceed(HttpEngine.java:760)
    at okhttp3.internal.http.HttpEngine.readResponse(HttpEngine.java:613)
    at okhttp3.RealCall.getResponse(RealCall.java:244)
    at okhttp3.RealCall$ApplicationInterceptorChain.proceed(RealCall.java:201)
    at okhttp3.RealCall.getResponseWithInterceptorChain(RealCall.java:163)
    at okhttp3.RealCall.execute(RealCall.java:57)
    at org.sonarqube.ws.client.HttpConnector.doCall(HttpConnector.java:201)
    ... 34 more
Caused by: java.io.EOFException: \n not found: size=0 content=?
    at okio.RealBufferedSource.readUtf8LineStrict(RealBufferedSource.java:215)
    at okhttp3.internal.http.Http1xStream.readResponse(Http1xStream.java:184)
```

Comment: Which version of SonarQube are you using ?

Comment: My SonarQube version is 6.0

Comment: Any one have any idea about this issue I am facing it daily